# Using SharePoint 2010 survey range from 1-5 to 5-1 when it is displayed in the survey

Tags: survey, rating

Using SharePoint 2010 survey and have a requirement to change the rating number range from 1-5 to 5-1 when it is displayed in the survey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need java script to get this done:
here is sample script, you have to modified it,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++)
{
if (tables[i].summary == 'Rating Scale Question')
{
var trs = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
var tds = trs[0].getElementsByTagName('td'); 
tds[2].colSpan = 1;
tds[2].innerHTML = 'your range text';
tds[3].colSpan = 1;
tds[3].innerHTML = 'your range text';
tds[4].colSpan = 1;
tds[4].innerHTML = 'your range text';
tds[5].colSpan = 1;
tds[5].innerHTML = 'your range text'; 
tds[6].colSpan = 1;
tds[6].innerHTML = 'your range text'; 
}
}
</script>
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dd6fa536-0cd8-4985-9926-f5a695adbbce/add-new-rating-scale-text-fields-in-sharepoint-survey?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

I have modified above javascript as below

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0; i<tables.length; i++)
{
if (tables[i].summary == 'Rating Scale Question')
{
var trs = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
var ths= trs[1].getElementsByTagName('th');
ths[0].colSpan = 1;
ths[0].innerHTML='5';
ths[1].colSpan = 1;
ths[1].innerHTML='4';
ths[2].colSpan = 1;
ths[2].innerHTML='3';
ths[3].colSpan = 1;
ths[3].innerHTML='2';
ths[4].colSpan = 1;
ths[4].innerHTML='1';
}
}
```